# Troubles executing an MacOsx script

Tags: macos, bash, shell, osx-elcapitan

I need to convert from ElCapitan.app to an .Iso image in order to use it on VirtualBox on windows 10. I have found this Script on the intenet:

```
    #!/bin/bash

    # Mount the installer image     
    hdiutil attach /Aplicaciones/Instalar\ OS\X\El\Capitan.app/Contents/SharedSupport/InstallESD.dmg -noverify -nobrowse -mountpoint /Volumes/install_app 

    # Create the ElCapitan Blank ISO Image of 7316mb with a Single Partition -Apple Partition Map
    hdiutil create -o /tmp/ElCapitan.cdr -size 7316m -layout SPUD -fs HFS+J  

    # Mount the ElCapitan Blank ISO Image
    hdiutil attach /tmp/ElCapitan.cdr.dmg -noverify -nobrowse -mountpoint/Volumes/install_build

    # Restore the Base System into the ElCapitan Blank ISO Image 
    asr restore -source /Volumes/install_app/BaseSystem.dmg -target /Volumes/install_build -noprompt -noverify -erase  

    # Remove Package link and replace with actual files  
    rm /Volumes/OS\ X\ Base\ System/System/Installation/Packages cp -rp /Volumes/install_app/Packages /Volumes/OS\ X\ Base\ System/System/Installation/ 

    # Copy El Capitan installer dependencies  
    cp -rp /Volumes/install_app/BaseSystem.dmg /Volumes/OS\ X\ Base\ System/BaseSystem.dmg

    # Unmount the installer image  
    hdiutil detach /Volumes/install_app  

    # Unmount the ElCapitan ISO Image  
    hdiutil detach /Volumes/OS\ X\ Base\ System/ 

     # Convert the ElCapitan ISO Image to ISO/CD master (Optional)  
     hdiutil convert /tmp/ElCapitan.cdr.dmg -format UDTO -o /tmp/ElCapitan.iso

    # Rename the ElCapitan ISO Image and move it to the desktop  
    mv /tmp/ElCapitan.iso.cdr ~/Desktop/ElCapitan.iso
```

I have given permissions 755 as well. Once executed (.txt, .rtf, .command) i'm getting this error:

```
    ./scriptcapitan.rtf: line 1: {rtf1ansiansicpg1252cocoartf1348cocoasubrtf170: command not found
    ./scriptcapitan.rtf: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
    ./scriptcapitan.rtf: line 2: `{\fonttbl\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Verdana;}'
```

Why i'm getting this error? Have I to convert  it to UTF-8?

Comment: You need to save the script as a plain text file, not an RTF file. The RTF file contains lots of formatting code that interferes with the shell interpreter.

Comment: @Albeis : chepner is right ! You should change the **File Format** when you save your file in TextEdit. Changing **extension**, don't change the **File Format** : it's two different things.

Comment: Thanks, finally i got it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the rtf document into a plain text document.

```
TextEdit Menu -> Format -> Make Plain Text(Shift-Command-T)
```

rtf documents have special formatting and text styles. The lines:

```
./scriptcapitan.rtf: line 1: {rtf1ansiansicpg1252cocoartf1348cocoasubrtf170: command not found
./scriptcapitan.rtf: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
./scriptcapitan.rtf: line 2: `{\fonttbl\f0\fnil\fcharset0 
Verdana;}'
```

define these parameters and are put above your code, you just can't see them in TextEdit.